# Why is patsy returning additional columns when I add a None value?

Tags: numpy, pandas, patsy

I'm using patsy to create matrices. But I get strange behavior when None or Nan values are in the dataset. As seen below instead of just dropping the None row it creates additional columns with 1's and 0's.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import patsy as pt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([(1,3),(2,6),(4,2),(6,3)]), columns=['y','X'])
In[60]: df
Out[60]: 
   y  X
0  1  3
1  2  6
2  4  2
3  6  3
In[61]: pt.dmatrices('y ~ X', df)
Out[61]: 
(DesignMatrix with shape (4, 1)
   y
   1
   2
   4
   6
   Terms:
     'y' (column 0),
 DesignMatrix with shape (4, 2)
   Intercept  X
           1  3
           1  6
           1  2
           1  3
   Terms:
     'Intercept' (column 0)
     'X' (column 1))
In[62]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([(1,3),(2,6),(4,2),(6,None)]), columns=['y','X'])
In[63]: pt.dmatrices('y ~ X', df)
Out[63]: 
(DesignMatrix with shape (3, 4)
   y[1]  y[2]  y[4]  y[6]
      1     0     0     0
      0     1     0     0
      0     0     1     0
   Terms:
     'y' (columns 0:4),
 DesignMatrix with shape (3, 3)
   Intercept  X[T.3]  X[T.6]
           1       1       0
           1       0       1
           1       0       0
   Terms:
     'Intercept' (column 0)
     'X' (columns 1:3))
```

Why is patsy returning additional columns when I add a None value?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, numpy array does not treat `None` as `nan` so the pandas dataframe takes that column as `object`. Since it's not a numerical column, patsy is trying to make a matrix for a categorical variable.

You can either skip the np.array and construct the matrix with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(1,3),(2,6),(4,2),(6,None)], columns=['y','X'])
```

Or you can just pass `np.nan` instead of None:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([(1,3),(2,6),(4,2),(6,np.nan)]), columns=['y','X'])
```

Result will be:

```
(DesignMatrix with shape (3L, 1L)
   y
   1
   2
   4
   Terms:
     'y' (column 0),
 DesignMatrix with shape (3L, 2L)
   Intercept  X
           1  3
           1  6
           1  2
   Terms:
     'Intercept' (column 0)
     'X' (column 1))
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the second answer should be:    df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([(1,3),(2,6),(4,2),(6,np.nan)]), columns=['y','X']) throws NameError: name 'nan' is not defined

Comment: You are right, Canopy imports them automatically so I forget to include np sometimes. Editing now.